# Can't clone from Bitbucket - Get stuck at "Cloning into..."

Tags: git

Maybe you can help me out.
I have a server which I'm accessing thru a SSH tunnel. On this server, I want to clone a git repo from bitbucket, but bitbucket uses Port 22 as well, I assume. So how can I clone the repo to my server using another port?

**fyi**
I came with this solution since I'm struggling with a weird error. When I try to clone a repo on the server, the program gets stuck at "Cloning into repository....".
After some googling, I found out that the connection to the repo server is "broken". So this is my guess why - I'm connecting to it using SSH.

Thx

**UPDATE** This is the console output

```
root@245:/path/to/dev# git clone git@bitbucket.org:123456789/repo.git
Cloning into repo...
```

and thats it. It gets stuck after "Cloning into dev"...

Comment: Am I correct in understanding you're opening an SSH connection to a machine, let's say MachineA, and from that machine, you're issuing a `git clone git@bitbucket.org:tutorials/mydvcsproject.git`, and that fails?  If that's the case, this doesn't sound like a port issue (an outbound connection will go out using a free, 'random' port, and connect to remote port 22 - your local port 22 isn't used for outgoing).  Also, the fact that you're seeing this when attempting to clone over HTTPS indicates this is not a port issue.  Can we see the full console output when you run your `git` command?

Comment: Also, you should edit the question - your real question is why you can't clone from bitbucket, and by going down this port path, you've asked an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ernie thanks for your reply. See the update above for the console output!

Comment: What's the https output?  Have you exchanged identities?  There's a [good tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) on setting up the connection.

Answer (score 15):

Run `ssh -vv git@bitbucket.org` to get more information. In my case the ssh client was trying to connect to bitbucket's IPv6 address but obviously the world is not yet ready.

I had to put this into "Host *" section of /etc/ssh/ssh_config to disable ssh connection over IPv6:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

Comment: 2019 and the world is still not prepared... Does anyone know the actual reason why using IPv6 won't work?

Comment: Wow thank you. Can confirm. 2020, we are really not prepared with everything that is currently happening!

Comment: Can confirm, at July 2020, the technology just still isn't there yet.

Comment: Today i had this problem with Bitbucket. All Ci-Pipelines stopped working. The above ssh test never ended connecting to Bitbucket. `AddressFamily inet` solved the problem.

Comment: Still waiting, in Nov 2022 :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are cloning into a nfs volume.

I had the same problem, then I figured out I was cloning a repo into a cifs shared volume mounted on my linux server and that was my problem. I solved using a nfs volume instead!

Answer (score 0):

Run ssh -vv git@bitbucket.org and check if the kind of IP is IPV4 or IPV6. If it is IPV6, you need change it to IPV4. Change the grub configuration:

1. #sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. Modify these line so:
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
3. Restart the SO (sudo update-grub didn't work for me)

That's all. Good look